# Kafka streams filtering: broker or consumer side?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

I am looking into kafka streams. I want to filter my stream, using a filter with very low selectivity (one in few thousands). I was looking at this method:
https://kafka.apache.org/0100/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/KStream.html#filter(org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Predicate)

But I can't find any evidence, if the filter will be evaluated by consumer (I really do not want to transfer a lot of GB to consumer, just to throw them away), or inside the broker (yay!).

If its evaluated on consumer side, is there any way, how to do this in broker?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Kafka does not support broker side filtering. If you use Streams API, filtering will be done in your application (the predicate will not be evaluated by `KafkaConsumer` but within a "processor node" of your topology -- ie, within Streams API runtime code).

This might help: https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/architecture.html

The reason for not supporting broker side filtering is, that brokers only use (1) byte arrays as key and value data types and use (2) zero-copy mechanism to achieve high throughput. Broker side filtering would required, to deserialize the data at the broker side what would be a major performance hit (deserialization cost and no zero-copy optimization).

Comment: well...I would be quite ok even with key only filtering. For me it would much smaller hit, if kafka just made possible to use "prefix" array filtering (my keys are strings and I can choose the prefix to be matched), than transferring many GB of data...

Comment: You can always create a feature request Jira: https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/KAFKA

Comment: good point. I created an improvement request: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-6020, let's see if they will like the idea :-)

Comment: Can you easily express your filtering rules as either a Kafka Connect SMT (Single Message Transform) or a KSQL statement? Those are the easiest ways to add inline filtering in a Kafka ingestion pipeline.

Comment: This is still a client side solution...my problem is that I do want to transmit those messages out of broker...

Comment: Yes, it is a client side solution. As first sentence of my answer is: "Kafka does not support broker side filtering." -- there is no broker side solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to do server-side filtering I would recommend using the [KSQL](https://www.confluent.io/product/ksql/). It supports a great SQL-like mechanism to filter messages on the server side. But for that you would have to spend more resources to setup a KSQL server and that involves high availability, replication among other concerns.

So if your message throughput is in the decimal thousands/sec then I would use KStreams, if it you have a larger amount and more complex filtering scenarios then I would go for KSQL.

Comment: Both KSQL and streams are client side

Comment: What do you mean by KSQL is client side? How does that setup works?

Comment: The question was about filtering inside the server (broker), so when you have streams of many GBs and low selectivity, bulk of the stream does not reach the consumers (applications). But KSQL and KStreams are client libraries == the full stream reaches all clients and they do the filtering.