# When does Kafka Streams de/serialize

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Under what circumstances does a Kafka Streams program need to serialize/deserialize?  Suppose we have the following simple program:

```
KStream<k,v> stream = ...;
Kstream<k,v> stream2 = stream.filter( predicateA )
Kstream<k,v> stream3 = stream2.filter( predicateB)
stream3.to( topic );
```

Very specifically, between the two invocations of `filter`, do the "k" and "v" get serialized/deserialized, or do individual data points get passed as native objects?

Comment: I guess https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/datatypes.html does not answer your question because it lists example operations rather than listing all or mentioning filter specifically. But https://stackoverflow.com/a/46611119/9705485 does suggest an answer.

Comment: Ryan, thanks.   It looks passing data between simple operations (e.g., `filter`) do not do serialization.   My interest in this was not so much about `filter` _per se_ but rather getting a feeling for how much de/serialization performance affects overall processing time.

Answer (score 1):

Kafka Streams tries to pass Java object around if this is possible to avoid de/serialization overhead.

Only if data is read or written into a topic or a store, it will be de/serialized.

All operators that might need to de/serialize data, allow you to specify a key and value `Serde`—this is a good indicator which operator might de/serialize data and which don't.